# In PostgreSQL is it possible to join between table and function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `Cars`
and a function named `PartsPerCar`

there is **no direct link** between `carid` and `partid`. the link is though 3 tables in the middle. I do have a function called `PartsPerCar` which gets `carid` (it goves via the tables in the middle) and give back all the `partid` related to `carid`.

for example : if I choose `carid=125` I can call `PartsPerCar(125)` and get:

```
part id    part name
10          Wheel A
12          Wheel D
13          Glass F
```

what I want to get eventualy is to get a list of all cars and all it's parts.

something like:

```
  Car ID ,   Part ID , Part Name
    1            15    engine A
    1            17    engine C
           .
           .
           .
    125         10     Wheel A
    125         12     Wheel D
    125         13     Glass F
```

the thing is that there is nothing to do join on.

I know I can do:

```
select PartsPerCar(carid)
from Cars
```

but it doesn't help me so much as I need the `partid` to use with the WHERE statement. In this way I can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table uses a `carid` value to retrieve the corresponding `part_id`s from function `PartsPerCar()` which returns a set of rows, a so-called [table function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM). In sub-section 5 (keep on reading) we see that

> Table functions appearing in FROM can also be preceded by the key word
>   LATERAL, but for functions the key word is optional; the function's
>   arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding FROM
>   items in any case.

You have all that you need to perform your query:

```
SELECT carid, partid, part_name
FROM cars, PartsPerCar(carid) AS carparts;
```

This creates a `CROSS JOIN` between the table `cars` and the set of records from the function `PartsPerCar()` but since the output of the latter is constrained by the parameter taken from the former it effectively works like a join condition.

Comment: It gives false result. I checked it with count. For Carid 539 i have 96 parts, if i change ur query to `SELECT carid, count (partid)
FROM cars, PartsPerCar(carid) AS carparts GROUP BY (carid)` it give on id 539 count of 960

Comment: And what do you get with `SELECT count(*) FROM PartsPerCar(539)`?

Comment: i get 96 which is the real count of parts for this carid. I think I know what the problem is. Table Cars isn't a list of unique Cars... there are 10 records there of car 539... it's working fine. Thank you.